# Disabling current button corresponding to current view wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to add style to my navigation, so when a user is on the currently selected view that corresponding button will be disabled because they don't need to click it when they are already there, so I've tried a view different test and nothing I'm trying to working out the way I wanted.

Here's the button code

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource NavButton}"
         Command="{Binding GotoDataMatrixCommand}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedView}"
         Tag="Document"
         Content="Enter Data">
 </Button>
```

Which I'm thinking I may need a converter for this?

Any way here is the MVVM snippets

```
#region Selected View
private object _selectedView;
private object _selectedViewBool;
public object SelectedView
{
   get { return _selectedView; }
   set
   {
      if (_selectedView == _currentView)
      {
         _selectedViewBool = false;
      }
      else
      {
         _selectedViewBool = true;
      }
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedView));
   }
}

#endregion

/// here is where I assign _selectedView
private void GoToErrorNotFound()
{
   CurrentTitleBar = "Error Page Not Found";
   CurrentView = _ErrorNotFound;
   _selectedView = _ErrorNotFound;

}
```

So my thinking was I'd test put the current view in a private object, later on testing the current view. Though my realization is that it would constantly be true (or false depending). I'm still working some things out though I wasn't sure if someone could help POINT me in the right direction, I don't need you to write everything or anything maybe tips on an easier way to determine "current button highlight"

As per request definition of commands

```
public ICommand GotoSafetySheetCommand
{
   get
   {
      return _gotoSafetySheetCommand ?? (_gotoSafetySheetCommand = new RelayCommand(
         x =>
         {
            GotoSafetySheet();
         }));
   }
}
```

This is my relay commands CS file

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
   private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
   private readonly Action<object> _execute;

   public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
      : this(execute, null)
   {
      _execute = execute;
   }

   public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
   {
      _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
      _canExecute = canExecute;
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
      return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
      _execute(parameter);
   }

   // Ensures WPF commanding infrastructure asks all RelayCommand objects whether their
   // associated views should be enabled whenever a command is invoked 
   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
   {
      add
      {
         CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
         CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
      }
      remove
      {
         CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
         CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
      }
   }

   private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

   public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
   {
      CanExecuteChangedInternal.Raise(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the definition and initialization of your `GotoDataMatrixCommand`?

Comment: updated with definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `bool` as property and use it. No converter is needed.

```
private object _selectedView;
private bool _selectedViewBool;

public bool SelectedViewBool
{
    get { return _selectedViewBool; }
    set
    {
        _selectedViewBool = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewBool));
    }
}

public object SelectedView
{
    get { return _selectedView; }
    set
    {
        _selectedView = value;
        SelectedViewBool = _selectedView != _currentView;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedView));
    }
}
```

```cs
private void GoToErrorNotFound()
{
    CurrentTitleBar = "Error Page Not Found";
    CurrentView = _ErrorNotFound; 
    SelectedView = _ErrorNotFound;
}
```

```xml
 <Button Style="{StaticResource NavButton}"
         Command="{Binding GotoDataMatrixCommand}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedViewBool}"
         Tag="Document"
         Content="Enter Data">
 </Button>
```

---

Or via `CanExecute` of `RelayCommand`

```cs
public ICommand GotoSafetySheetCommand
    => _gotoSafetySheetCommand ?? (_gotoSafetySheetCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        GotoSafetySheet();
    }, parameter => _selectedView != _currentView));
```

The `RelayCommand` which I'm using, for visibility:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Comment: @EasyBB added `CanExecute` solution that may be replacement of `IsEnabled` Binding. The enabled state of the button using this [`RelayCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) will be updated on every input event (mouse click, keyboard input). If you want to update the button state manually from the code, simply call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` (in UI thread).

Comment: Hey so when I use this, all buttons become disabled.

Comment: @EasyBB `, parameter => _selectedView != _currentView` is responsible on disable. Remove it from all commands except one.

Comment: Removed it all except one, and that one is the only one being disabled now. I think I'm testing the wrong parameters to be honest

Comment: @EasyBB probably yes. It's just a predicate (returning `bool` function) that will be re-requested on each input event (key press/mouse click). Simply use proper expression which fits your needs.

Comment: I figured out the test, I should have been checking `_DataMatrix != _currentView` on each command and changing `_DataMatrix` to corresponding command

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `Command` in conjuction with an `IsEnabled` binding. An [`ICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netcore-3.1) already provides a means to determine when to enable a control and that is the [`CanExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Input_ICommand_CanExecute_System_Object_) method.

Initialize your command with a `CanExecute` delegate that checks the condition that needs to be satisfied in order to enable the control and remove the `IsEnabled` binding. Controls will determine their `IsEnabled` state based on the `CanExecute` method of a bound command, whenever its [`CanExecuteChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged?view=netcore-3.1) event is raised and when it is initially bound.

I do not know which command implementation you use, so I will provide an example with a simple `RelayCommand` from the [Microsoft command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand#the-relaycommand) and a sample view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public ICommand GotoDataMatrixCommand { get; }

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      GotoDataMatrixCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteGotoDataMatrixCommand, CanExecuteGotoDataMatrixCommand); 
   }

   private void ExecuteGotoDataMatrixCommand()
   {
      // ...your command execution code.
   }

   private bool CanExecuteGotoDataMatrixCommand()
   {
      return _selectedView != _currentView;
   }
}
```

In addition, you have to ensure to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event whenever your condition changes (or any properties or fields that affect the condition are modified) to notify controls that bind the command to requery if the command can be executed and to set their `IsEnabled` state based on that.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   // ...this is a sample method that changes _selectedView, _currentView or both
   // so you have to raise the "CanExecuteChanged" event of the command to notify
   // controls to reevalute the `CanExecuteMethod` to get the correct enabled state
   
   GotoDataMatrixCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChange();
}
```

The `RaiseCanExecuteChange` method might be specific to this command implementation, yours could be different.

---

Update for your edits. You have to create a `CanExecuteSafetySheet` method as shown above and assign it to your `RelayCommand`.

```
public ICommand GotoSafetySheetCommand
{
   get
   {
      return _gotoSafetySheetCommand ?? (_gotoSafetySheetCommand = new RelayCommand(
         _ => GotoSafetySheet(),
         _ => CanExecuteSafetySheet()));
   }

   private bool CanExecuteSafetySheet()
   {
      return _selectedView != _currentView;
   }
}
```

With your `RelayCommand` implementation you would have to call this **whenever you change** `_selectedView` or `_currentView` to trigger a reevaluation of `CanExecute` on controls:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
```

However, I recommend you to change `RelayCommand` instead. Remove the `CanExecuteChangedInternal` event and its usages. It does not seem to be useful in any way. Then adapt the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method.

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
   CanExecuteChanged.Raise(this);
}
```

Now instead of using the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`, you call:

```
GotoSafetySheetCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

Comment: I've updated my OP with my relay commands, with your view on this which is new for me i'm delving into MVVM. So would I need to update and change (or add new execute commands) for this to work properly? As of right now all my buttons go to disabled so something is messed up on my end